# how to show plot in other screen kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

i tried to show a plot in second screen after i clicked the button in the first screen.
this is the code that i tried.
        import kivy
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.label import Label
    from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
    from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
    from kivy.uix.button import Button
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
    from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
    from kivy.lang import Builder
    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
    from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
    from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
    from pandas import read_excel
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
plt.plot([1, 23, 2, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')

class MainWindow(Screen):
    def btn(self):
        print("name: ",self.name2.text)
        self.ids.destination.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")

class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__=="__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()


    #:kivy 1.9.1
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"
    name2: name2

    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size: root.width, root.height

        GridLayout:
            cols:2

            Label:
                text:"name: "

            TextInput:
                id: name
                multinline:False

            Label:
                text:"name2: "

            TextInput:
                id: name2
                multinline:False

        Button:
            text:"Submit"

            on_release:
                root.btn()
                app.root.current = "second"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"

    GridLayout:
        cols:1

        BoxLayout:
            id: destination

        Button:
            text: "Go Back"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "main"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

but i got error says `'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'` and i don't know what it means. please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use an `id` that is defined in a different `Screen`. The `destination` is defined in `SecondWindow`, so `MainWindow` knows nothing about it. So, you can reference that `id` by going through `SecondWindow` like this:

```
class MainWindow(Screen):
    def btn(self):
        print("name: ",self.name2.text)
        self.manager.get_screen('second').ids.destination.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))
```